# Sequelize read replication causes error on read queries

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sequelize.js, amazon-rds

We're setting up our sequelize options with the following information to try to connect to AWS RDS Proxy reader/writer instances

```
let sequelizeOptions: any = {
  logging: console.log,
  dialect: 'mysql',
  dialectModule: mysql2,
  dialectOptions: {decimalNumbers: true},
  replication: {
    read: [{host: readonlyHost, password}],
    write: {host: defaultHost, password},
  },
  username,
  port,
  database,
  models: [modelPath + '/!(index).*'],
};

const signer = new AWS.RDS.Signer({
    region: region,
    hostname: {defaultHost},
    port: port,
    username: username,
});
const IamAuthToken = signer.getAuthToken({username});
const readonlySigner = new AWS.RDS.Signer({
    region: region,
    hostname: {readonlyHost},
    port: port,
    username: username,
});
const readonlyIamAuthToken = readonlySigner.getAuthToken({username});

sequelizeOptions.replication.read[0].password = readonlyIamAuthToken;
sequelizeOptions.replication.write.password = IamAuthToken;
```

This works perfectly fine when using the write instance but when we're attempting to read from a table we get the following error. `{readonlyHost}` and `{defaultHost}` used in place of the AWS proxy endpoint for security purposes.

```
2021-12-09T21:12:57.108Z [INFO] [proxyEndpoint={readonlyHost}] [clientConnection=12345678] Proxy authentication with IAM authentication failed for user "{username}" with TLS on. Reason: The proxy couldn't authenticate using IAM. The expected "Proxy endpoint DNS name" value is "{readonlyHost}" but was "{defaultHost}". Generate a new authentication token and use it in a new client connection.
```

Comment: Probably doesn't matter, but why is `replication.read` an array with only a single item and `replication.write` is an object?

Comment: @MetroSmurf We simply followed the documentation. https://sequelize.org/master/manual/read-replication.html